# How to restrict/limit Azure App Registration API permissions

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service

We have an Azure AD App Registration which calls into Microsoft Graph API using Application rather than Delegated permissions.

Examples of the MS Graph API permissions we've added are:

- User.Read.All
- GroupMember.ReadWrite.All

Our goal is to only allow this Application to manage those users and groups within a specific 'Administrative Unit', however we are unable to see how to restrict or scope the above permissions.

Do you know if this is possible and if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we ended up doing was:

- Remove the GroupMember.ReadWrite.All permission from the App registration
- Customise the User Administrator role from within the Administrative Unit as per screenshot below.
- As commented by @Clayton when selecting the member (in this case the service principal of the App) you'll need to enter the name exactly (or paste in the App ID) in order for it to appear in the search results.

[image]

- This links the service principal for the app to the User Admin role, but is scoped to the Admin Unit.
- Restart the app to ensure it picks up new tokens
- Our testing so far confirms that the app may now only add users to groups which are within this Admin Unit
- Any attempt to add a user to a different Admin Unit or a group with no Admin unit will fail.

Hope this helps someone (or me in the future!)

Comment: Trying to do the same thing... Stuck on the last step. When you go to select the member/Service Principal you can only select users or groups of users. How do you select the App Registration? thx

Comment: Try pasting in the id of the app registration and see if the apps service principal appears.  I've just tested it and it still works for me. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @BigJump.

FYI to others: the azure list filter is inconsistent. I was searching based on a unique sting in the middle of the name. This works when searching for apps within "app registrations". But the list filter with AU/Roles/Add Member does NOT work that way. You need to type the full name, or paste the app ID and then it can be granted.

Comment: Glad you got it working @Clayton - yes I think the search experience in the Azure Portal is inconsistent like this in a few places.  Hopefully it will improve over time.  If my original answer worked for you, any chance of an upvote? :)

Comment: Typically using an AU requires a P1 License be applied to the AU admin. When I go to license assignment, the app reg is not shown (tried full name and AppId#). Did you have to apply a license to the AppReg or did it work for you without this? Waiting to hear back from developer I am working with, but they are other side of the world.

Comment: I'm not aware that you can assign a license to the AU or App Reg - I was under the impression it's applied to the entire AD tenant.  We are on P2, but I don't believe we had to do anything re. licensing to get this working.  Do your AD credentials allow you to list the App Registrations in the portal?

Comment: Have global admin, so can see App Registrations. Up until now I've worked more with 365 licenses that are per user. I do see now that azure licenses are per tenant. Funny, don't recall Az900 or Az305 mentioning Az licenses being per tenant. Still waiting on my dev team, fingers crossed.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/license-users-groups

Answer (score 1):

Use the `New-ApplicationAccessPolicy` cmdlet to restrict or deny access to a specific set of mailboxes by an application that uses APIs (Outlook REST, Microsoft Graph, or Exchange Web Services (EWS)).

Configure **ApplicationAccessPolicy**.
To configure an application access policy and limit the scope of application permission

**1)**  Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell. For details, see [Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps)

**2)**   Identify the app’s client ID and a mail-enabled security group to restrict the app’s access to. Identify the app’s application (client) ID in the Azure app registration portal. Create a new mail-enabled security group or use an existing one and identify the email address for the group.

**3)**   Create an application access policy. Run the following command, replacing the AppId, PolicyScopeGroupId, and Description arguments.

Example:

```
New-ApplicationAccessPolicy -AccessRight RestrictAccess -AppId "e7e4dbfc-046f-4074-9b3b-2ae8f144f59b" -PolicyScopeGroupId EvenUsers@AppPolicyTest2.com -Description "Restrict this app's access to members of security group EvenUsers."
```

This example creates a new application access policy with the following settings:

AccessRight: RestrictAccess,
AppIDs: e7e4dbfc-046f-4074-9b3b-2ae8f144f59b,
PolicyScopeGroupId: EvenUsers@AppPolicyTest2.com,
Description: Restrict this app's access to members of security group EvenUsers.

**4)**   Test the newly created application access policy. Run the following command, replacing the AppId and Identity arguments.

```
Test-ApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity user1@contoso.com -AppId e7e4dbfc-046-4074-9b3b-2ae8f144f59b
```

The output of this command will indicate whether the app has access to User1’s mailbox

For more details refer these [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#calendars-permissions) and [link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-applicationaccesspolicy?view=exchange-ps)

Comment: Thanks but that’s for Mailboxes only - I’m looking to restrict the entire scope of the Graph API calls to a single AdministratrativenUnit. 

I may have found a way - still testing and will update once I know.